# Vuetify App Bar too tall - takes up half the screen

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When I have an otherwise empty app with a [`v-app-bar`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars#app-bars) inside of the [`v-app`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application#application) container, the app bar takes up half of the page.

```html
<v-app>

  <v-app-bar color="deep-purple" dark >
    <v-toolbar-title>Page title</v-toolbar-title>
  </v-app-bar>

  <v-content>
    Hello Vue
  </v-content>

</v-app>
```

#### [Demo in Codepen](https://codepen.io/KyleMit/pen/jgmRjV?editors=1010)

[image: Screenshot Example]

I've tried adding options for `dense`, `short`, & `height` but they don't seem to have any affect.

The docs have plenty of code samples with this exact App Bar markup, so I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to add the `app` property to `v-app-bar` like this:

```html
<v-app>

  <v-app-bar color="deep-purple" dark app >
    <v-toolbar-title>Page title</v-toolbar-title>
  </v-app-bar>

  <v-content>
    Hello Vue
  </v-content>

</v-app>
```

The key here is all child elements in the App component must indicate whether they should use the app layout

From [Vuetify > Components > Application > Default Markup](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application#default-application-markup):

> You can place your layout elements anywhere, as long as you apply the **`app`** property.

From [Vuetify > Components > App Bar > API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application#default-application-markup):

> **`app`**
>   Designates the component as part of the application layout. Used for dynamically adjusting content sizing. Components using this prop should reside *outside* of `v-content` component to function properly.

[image: Screenshot of Fix]

Comment: `v-content` is now deprecated. Use `v-main` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add the class="flex-grow-0" to your app-bar. This will prevent your problem.

Comment: This is a hacky way to correct the issue. Use the "app" property as instructed in KyleMit's answer.

Answer (score 0):

rounding v-app-bar tag with nav tag will work fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom height using the following

```
<v-app-bar color="blue accent-3" height="200px" dark >
```